# Copy first value in group to all rows where condition holds

Tags: python, pandas

updated

I have a Pandas Dataframe and want to use a value from the row before on condition

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 2],
                        [1, 4],
                        [1, 2],
                        [1, 3],
                        [1, 2],
                        [5, 3],
                        [1, 4]],
                  columns=['A', 'B'])


df.loc[df.A < df.B, 'B'] =  df.B.shift(1)
df.loc[df.A >= df.B, 'B'] =  df.B
```

the output:

```
   A    B
0  1  NaN
1  1  2.0
2  1  4.0
3  1  2.0
4  1  3.0
5  5  3.0
6  1  3.0
```

but what I intend to get is the following:

```
   A    B
0  1  NaN
1  1  2.0
2  1  2.0
3  1  2.0
4  1  2.0
5  5  3.0
6  1  3.0
```

so how can I basically "write" the result of `df.B.shift(1)` in the data frame so the next line can use it again?

If the condition is met take the result from the line before, if not keep the value.

Comment: Can you please provide a better example, for example, with rows in the middle where df.A >= df.B? It isn't clear how the answer emerges from this input.

Comment: I updated the data, is it clearer?

Comment: Sure, but I'm still not clear on what "how can I basically "write" the result of df.B.shift(1) in the data frame so the next line can use it again?" means. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Lastly, it doesn't make sense why the first row is NaN in B. Is that deliberate?

Comment: with "writing" (sorry for the unclear term) I mean that the value is set in the dataframe as the new value and if the condition is true again it can be used. I guess my approach is just not the write one and I would have to go through the data frame row by row? the NaN in B is not deliberate, but not a problem.

Comment: Okay, will you please look at the answers below and see which of them are correct according to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a `groupby` transforming `first`:

```
df['B'] = df.groupby((df['A'] >= df['B']).cumsum())['B'].transform('first')
df
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  2
2  1  2
3  1  2
4  1  2
5  5  3
6  1  3
```

Comment: @user3113106 sure thing and thanks for accepting. You can also upvote if you found the answer helpful. Thanks.